# How can I remove a value from a combox after setting its datasource?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, datasource

With this code:

```
comboBoxCurrently.DataSource = PlatypusData.getCurrentlyVals();
comboBoxCurrently.Items.Remove("Surrounded by purplish-blue Penguins");
```

...I get, "*System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.*"

I don't want to restrict the value I'm later removing from within the query (*...WHERE bla <> 'Surrounded...*), because sometimes that value *IS* allowed (to display historical data), and I don't really want to have a conditional statement in **getCurrentlyVals()** that uses either one query statement or the other (if there is a better way to do it).

Any ideas?

### UPDATED

OK, this worked:

```
List<string> intermediateList = PlatypusData.getCurrentlyVals();
intermediateList.Remove("Surrounded by purplish-blue Penguins");
comboBoxCurrently.DataSource = intermediateList;
```

### UPDATED AGAIN

I changed that to Lars' way:

```
comboBoxCurrently.Items.AddRange(PlatypusData.getCurrentlyVals().ToArray());
comboBoxCurrently.Items.Remove("Surrounded by purplish-blue Penguins");
```

...and I reckon this page has more intances of the string "Surrounded by purplish-blue Penguins" than any page in the history of mankind, past or future.

Comment: Your first way is perfectly acceptable for what you wanted to do, and I would almost prefer that to the `AddRange` solution I posted.

Comment: OK, actually I did just get this from ReSharper on the AddRange line: "Co-variant array conversion from string[] to object can cause run-time exception on write operation"

Comment: That's why I liked the `List<string>` version better.  If getCurrentlyVals returns a list of KeyValuePair objects for instance, the AddRange would barf on the ToArray part.  But for just strings, it works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to modify the collection from the DataSource, but you seem to be against doing that, so in that case, don't use a DataSource, but try adding the items to the ComboBox directly:

```
comboBoxCurrently.Items.AddRange(PlatypusData.getCurrentlyVals().ToArray());
comboBoxCurrently.Items.Remove("Surrounded by purplish-blue Penguins");
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind comboBoxCurrently.DataSource to a public property

E.G.

```
Public ObservableCollection<string> AnimalList { get; set; }
```

In the Ctor  AnimalList =  PlatypusData.getCurrentlyVals();

Then AnimalList.Remove("Surrounded by purplish-blue Penguins");